# Creating categories.php page to grab data from MySQL & use it has different categories

Tags: php, mysql, get, categories

I was thinking how to create a page called categories.php that will look exactly like my index.php, and for example, when I click category 1 it will view all the things that belong to category 1, when I click category 2, it will view all the things that belong to category 2 and so on...
I have a table in PHPMYADMIN called: games, and inside it there are games with parameters like: game_id, game_name... and the most important for my question is: game_categories...
I want to create a php script that will "$_GET" to my categories.php page lets say, games from the category of "sports" when I click on "Sports" on my navigation bar...
Any suggestions? :)

Comment: I would suggest you to look at what a CMS is .

Comment: Its ok, Im using CMS with my website... after 1 hour of thinking I finally solved it :)